# Prediction.io - Elasticsearch error

Tags: elasticsearch, predictionio

I'm trying to install [Prediction.io](https://predictionio.apache.org/start/) on virtualBox ubuntu 16.04 version. 
Following is configured pio-env.sh

```
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_METADATA_NAME=pio_metadata
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_METADATA_SOURCE=ELASTICSEARCH

PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_EVENTDATA_NAME=pio_event
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_EVENTDATA_SOURCE=HBASE

PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_MODELDATA_NAME=pio_model
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_MODELDATA_SOURCE=LOCALFS
```

After running command

```
PredictionIO-0.12.0-incubating/dist/bin/pio status
```

Getting below output

```
[INFO] [Management$] Inspecting PredictionIO...
[INFO] [Management$] PredictionIO 0.12.0-incubating is installed at /home/aniruddha/PredictionIO-0.12.0-incubating/dist
[INFO] [Management$] Inspecting Apache Spark...
[INFO] [Management$] Apache Spark is installed at /home/aniruddha/PredictionIO-0.12.0-incubating/dist/vendors/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.6
[INFO] [Management$] Apache Spark 2.1.1 detected (meets minimum requirement of 1.3.0)
[INFO] [Management$] Inspecting storage backend connections...
[INFO] [Storage$] Verifying Meta Data Backend (Source: ELASTICSEARCH)...
[ERROR] [Management$] Unable to connect to all storage backends successfully.
The following shows the error message from the storage backend.

PUT http://localhost:9200/pio_metadata/_mapping/engine_instances: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [keyword] declared on field [status]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [keyword] declared on field [status]"},"status":400} (org.apache.predictionio.shaded.org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException)

Dumping configuration of initialized storage backend sources.
Please make sure they are correct.

Source Name: ELASTICSEARCH; Type: elasticsearch; Configuration: HOME -> /home/aniruddha/PredictionIO-0.12.0-incubating/dist/vendors/elasticsearch-5.5.2, HOSTS -> localhost, PORTS -> 9200, SCHEMES -> http, CLUSTERNAME -> prediction, TYPE -> elasticsearch
```

I'm new to prediction.io, tried to install by referring installation manual - https://predictionio.apache.org/install/install-sourcecode/